# Trying to make a footer with buttons floated to the left and right

Tags: html, css

I would like this code to resemble the bottom of Google's homepage. It is still listing vertically, even with "inline". I want each three "lists" to be next to each other horizontally on the left and right side of the screen.

```
#HTML
<footer>
<div class="footer">
<ul style="width:10%; float:left;list-style-type:none;">
      <li>Advertising</li>
      <li>Business</li>
      <li>About</li>
   </ul>

   <ul style="width:10%; float:right;list-style-type:none;">
      <li>Privacy</li>
      <li>Terms</li>
      <li>Settings</li>
   </ul>
</div>
</footer>

#CSS

.footer li{
  display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the width on your `ul`s. See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZxdwy). Floating elements will take the width of all their children. By wrapping them in an element that take 10% of the width, they don't have enough space to stay on the same row.

Comment: Thankyou that worked. Any idea how to make it all move to the very bottom of the page?

Comment: See this codepen for an example of footer always on the bottom of the page : https://codepen.io/JesmoDrazik/pen/jPqjgR

Answer (score 1):

You could use `display: flex;` on the `.footer` DIV, with settings as below

```css
.footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.footer li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer">
    <ul>
      <li>Advertising</li>
      <li>Business</li>
      <li>About</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li>Privacy</li>
      <li>Terms</li>
      <li>Settings</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```